# Batch requests with the REST API: Is it synchronous or asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, rest, 2016, sharepoint-rest-api

Simple question: is the *batch* request in the [SharePoint 2016 REST API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/make-batch-requests-with-the-rest-apis) asynchronous or synchronous (for clarification: the multiple requests inside one batch are handled one after one [synchronous] or all at once [asynchronous])?

I could not find anything about this topic...

Comment: I would guess that they are synchronous as the order of batched operations is often important. For example, create an order header and then order details. Some info here: http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/part-1-sharepoint-rest-api-batching-understanding-batching-requests and http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/part-2-sharepoint-rest-api-batching-exploring-batch-requests-responses-and-changesets

Comment: This is also my guess but a guess is only a guess and do not provide sufficient basis for definite conclusions ;-)

Comment: I can't find anything that suggests otherwise. Maybe run some tests with a batch that creates an item and deletes the same item and run it many times to see if it ever fails.